# Unknown Database when calling PDO(), for a MySQL database created on phpMyAdmin using WAMPServer 3.2.0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, wampserver

I created a MySQL database 'testdatabase' using phpMyAdmin associated to installed WAMPServer v-3.2.0, however, when i try connecting to the database using php as listed in my code below:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=testdatabase", $username, $password);
```

the exception getMessage and getTraceAsString prints the following error message:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'testdatabase'#0 C:\wamp64\www\TestProject\test.php(10): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', NULL) #1 {main}

Note: when trying to connect to system defined databases such as "mysql" and "information_schema" it echoes "Connected successfully".

Why can't PDO recognize "testdatabase"?

Comment: Do you have multiple mysql services installed on your computer?

Comment: No, only MySQL 8.0.18 associated to the WAMPServer installation

Comment: can you try to use non-NULL root password? or different mysql account that has all the permissions for testdatabase

Comment: Check this - $password

Comment: @Wizard, i tried assigning a password to the root user but same error occuredm as when created new user and ran same function, the following message was displayed "Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'Boss'@'localhost' (using password: YES)", although MADE SURE having granted all permissions on "testdatabase" to `Boss`@`localhost`

Comment: If you use wamp then you probably have mariadb installed too. Verify which one you are connecting to.

Comment: @Dharman - Correct i disabled MariaDB and associated the port number used by MySQL to the $servername variable and it connected to the database successfuly, Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Check if there is the port in your **$servername**, like localhost:8080

Comment: There is a port number, but specifying the port number in the $servername displayed the following message "Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away"

Comment: BTW mysql servers usually don't listen on 8080.

Comment: Yeah, that's why if he has :8080 in the $servername, it doesn't works...